# signals/slots setup in Dock widget that contains many tab widgets

Tags: qt, widget, signals-slots, qdockwidget

I have a class that inherits QDockWidget. This class has four QTabWidgets in it (tcp stuff, ftp stuff, sql stuff and settings), each of which has its own functionality meaning each one has different signals/slots that need to be captured or called. Each tab has a few signals/slots that are important for the main UI to capture or call.Is there a way to prevent having to litter my QDockWidget class with signals and slots from the tab widgets it contains or is this just how it needs to be done?

Comment: The QDockWidget class doesn't need to know anything about the signals that pass between the QTabWidgets and the main window.

Comment: But the first parameter of connect() is the object that emits the signal, so how can I capture a signal from a tab widget encapsulated in the QDockWidget if the Main Window only knows of the QDockWidget?

Comment: The tab widgets can call connect().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define getter functions in the header file of your QDockWidget subclass like:

```
inline QWidget* tcpStuffWidget() { return <pointer_to_widget>; }
```

and in the main UI you can then do something like

```
connect( dockWidget()->tcpStuffWidget(), SIGNAL( ... ),
         this                          , SLOT  ( ... ) );
```

Comment: So I'm simply going to have to litter my main UI code with connect(..) then?

Comment: You can place the connect statements anywhere you like, as long as you have a pointer to the sender and the receiver at that location.